# How to count the number of occurences of an event in a date R studio

Tags: r, date, dplyr, group-by, count

I want to know how I can extract the number of times events occured for each date.
My dataset looks like this:

```
Date            burstID
2018-09-18      1
2018-09-18      2
2018-09-18      3
2018-09-18      4
```

Basically for each date I need to count the number of times we have bursts with burstID. I've tried multiple things like:

```
numberofburst <- df %>% group_by(Date) %>% count(burstID)
```

But it returns a new column n that specifies the number of burst per ID (always 1), which is not what I mean.

Any help please ?

Comment: Is the expected result 10 or 4? Or something else?

Comment: You don't to group_by date: `df |> 
  count(Date, name = "Count")`

Comment: Based on their comment below (in the form of an answer, oddly) it seems they haven't correctly expressed their problem.    @Skyk - please provide example input and desired output as at present it's not clear what you want.  In particular, "number of independent burst" - do you not want to count as two if the burstID is the same?  Your example data doesn't feature that as a possiblity.

Comment: yes ! That's what Maël answered, sorry for that I got to understand by myself. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this for counting?

```
df %>%
    summarise(count = n(), .by = Date)
```

which gives

```
        Date count
1 2018-09-18     4
```